# Laravel exception on WAMP windows server

Tags: apache, laravel, wamp, windows-server-2012-r2

I have installed a Laravel application on **WAMP** in a window server and I receive this error:

```
"Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()"
```

I cannot figure out the reason.

> -- UPDATE --

I found out that MCrypt module is missing from the php extension folder, now the problem is how to install it :)

Comment: LAMP (Linux Apache MySQL PHP) is for Linux systems! You should probably use WAMP (Windows Apache MySQL PHP)

Comment: Lapsus, I ment Wamp

Comment: did you enable, extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini?

Comment: yes it is enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Enable this extension (`php_mcrypt.dll`) in your `php.ini` file:

```
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
```

And then restart WAMP.

**Solution 2:**

For laravel look into  `config/app.php` under `'cipher'` and replace `CRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` with `'AES-128-CBC'`

Comment: Addes extension=php_mcrypt.dll and set cipher on aes-128-cbc, but now i receive, the only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC

Comment: I donwloaded `php_mcrypt.dll` from here: http://www.dlldownloader.com/php_mcrypt-dll/ and in `php.ini` I added new line as `extension=php_mcrypt.dll`, restarted WAMP, and it works now. Thanks.

Comment: Warning: This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 7.1.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.2.0. If you run into that problem, better update WAMPServer AND PHP AND Apache AND Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update Wampserver, PHP AND Apache:

```
Exit running Wamp Server

From [Wamp][1]:
- Install the Visual c++ packages,
- Update Wamp Server
- Update PHP
- Update Apache

Switch to the newest PHP:
 - Wamp TrayIcon->PHP->Version-> 7.x.x

Switch to the newest Apache Version
 - Wamp TrayIcon->Apache->Version-> 2.x.x
```

Answer (score 0):

Make enable `extension=openssl` in both php.ini files, php and apache directories